# Returning an error instead of raising it from python C API

Tags: python, error-handling, pybind11, c-api

Whether or not it is a good idea (and it probably is considered bad practice), I sometimes return an Error in python instead of raising it.

```py
def fnA( some_param ):
   # use some_param in complicated thing
   if some_param is None:
      return ValueError( "something went wrong" )

def fnB( param_a ):
   val = fnA( param_a )
   if isinstance( val, Exception ):
      # error path
```

I have been trying to create a python C extension from a regular module that I have written both as practice and because I think it could benefit from it.  To do that, I have been using pybind11.  It covers most of my needs, except that.  I cannot seem to create a ValueError and return it from C (or C++ in this case).

I have looked at the documentation, at python's own source code and I have not found a way to create an exception without raising it.  What I have "found"/tried is this:

```c
auto some_fn() -> PyExc_ValueError* {
   PyObject* type;
   PyObject* value;
   PyObject* traceback;

   PyErr_SetString( PyExc_ValueError, "error in my function !!!" );
   PyErr_Fetch( &type, &value, &traceback );
   PyErr_NormalizeException( &type, &value, &traceback );
   if( traceback != NULL ) {
      PyException_SetTraceback( value, traceback );
   }
   PyErr_Clear();
   return value;
}
```

which sets the exception, fetches it, normalizes it, clears it and returns the concrete error.  I thought it would work but it does not even compile.

Anyone can point me in the right direction for creating and returning an exception in the C API?  It might not really be possible, but then again, it is so easy in python code, I have a hard time believing it can't be done.

Thanks in any case.

Comment: For a bit of follow-up, I have found a way via pybind.  I am importing the ValueError object from the builtins module via py::module_::import("builtins").attr("ValueError").  And then, I call the type with a message and return it.  I am still curious how this would be done in the C API, so I am leaving the question open.